# How to format decimal merge field to display numbers without extra padding?

Tags: ms-word, word-2010

I'm having trouble formatting a decimal number to be displayed with a thousand separator and a decimal separator if needed. Number can have up to three decimal digits. I have a feeling that I'm missing something very obvious here.

Basically:

```
1 -> 1
1.11 -> 1.11
1.111 -> 1.111
```

I have been using codes for formatting number and so far I've tried this combinations:

```
\# ,0
\# ,0.000
\# ,#
\# ,#.###
\# #,#
\# #,#.###
```

Basically, for a value of 1.11 I've gotten either a 1 as a result or 1.110 as a result.

Comment: Your last sample - `\# #'#.###` - works for me (except that the thousands separator for me is an ampersand, not a comma). You should perhaps check your thousands and decimal separator settings under Windows.

Comment: One would have to ask why you need a numeric picture switch at all - your number should be returned as it exists in the data source; it's usually only when you want to format it differently that you'd need a switch.

Comment: @CindyMeister I've checked once more and it doesn't work for me ie. I get 1.110 as a result.

Comment: @macropod The database returns a padded number 1.110 for example. I do need to format it differently.

Comment: Might be best to pre-process the data with a query in the database that "cleans up the data" and link the mail merge to that...

Answer (score 3):

Given your most recent comment (i.e. "The database returns a padded number 1.110 for example"), your data don't have '*up to* three decimal digits'; they have *exactly* three decimal digits. If this is for a mailmerge, you could obtain both the thousands separator and suppression of trailing 0s with a field coded as:

{={MERGEFIELD MyField} # ,0.###}

Where the number ends with a trailing decimal 0, you'll end up with a space where the 0 would otherwise be and, where it's an integer, you'll end up with a trailing decimal point. If you really want to omit all this trailing stuff, you should modify the data so it's stored in the appropriate format; otherwise some fairly complex field coding will be required to achieve your desired outcome:

{QUOTE{SET Val {MERGEFIELD MyField}}{IF{=INT(Val) # 0.000}= {REF Val} {=INT(Val) # ,0} {IF{=INT(Val*10)/10 # 0.000}= {REF Val} {=Val # ,0.0} {IF{=INT(Val*100)/100 # 0.000}= {REF Val} {=Val # ,0.00} {=Val # ,0.000}}}}}

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above examples are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required.

Comment: Wow. That is a complex solution, no doubt about it. The number in question is a quantity field and in 99% of the cases it's an integer. User reasonably wants to have a report that is 'clean' especially if there is a list of items with quantity of 1 which is most often the case. But sometimes it's 0.125 or something like that and the report needs to be correct.